# play and pause music with toggle button

Tags: android, media-player, togglebutton

I'm trying to play music when the user clicks in the **MUSIC ON** toggle button, and music will pause when he clicks in **MUSIC OFF**. I also need to play music when opening the app. This is my code but doesn't work:

```
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.vapor);
    mediaPlayer.start();
     ..... 
    }
 MusicButton = (ToggleButton)findViewById(R.id.toggleButton);
    MusicButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(MusicButton.isChecked()){
                mediaPlayer.start();
            }
            else{
                mediaPlayer.stop();
                mediaPlayer.release();
            }
        }
    });

@Override
public void onPause() {
    mediaPlayer.stop();
    mediaPlayer.release();
    super.onPause();
}

@Override
public void onResume() {
    mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.vapor);
    mediaPlayer.setLooping(false);
    mediaPlayer.start();
    super.onResume();
}
```

Error log:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException
>                                                                                  at android.media.MediaPlayer._start(Native Method)
>                                                                                  at android.media.MediaPlayer.start(MediaPlayer.java:1384)
>                                                                                  at com.myapp$MainActivity$2.onClick(MainActivity.java:80)

Answer (score 0):

first,you should not use `setOnClickListener()` on `ToggleButton`,`ToggleButton` has function `setOnCheckedChangeWidgetListener` to listene the status of compent
second,about you error,maybe your `ToggleButton` is unchecked,when you clicked it, `ToggleButton` become checked and invoke you code `mediaPlayer.start();`,but you start mediaPlayer at `onCreate()` already,you can check it.